# Switch IN while? Not sure if this is how to do it

Tags: php, while-loop

```
<?php 
$x = 1;

while($x <= 17) {

switch($x) {
    case 1: $sdg_text = "End poverty in all its forms everywhere";
    case 2: $sdg_text = 'End hunger, achieve food security and improved nutrition and promote sustainable agriculture';
    case 3: $sdg_text = "Ensure healthy lives and promote well-being for all at all ages";
    default: echo '';
} 
?>
    <div class='grid-20 mobile-grid-100'>
        <ul class="img-list">
            <li>
                <a>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/sdg/sdg<?php echo $x?>.svg" />
                    <span class="text-content"><span><?php echo $sdg_text; ?></span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
<?php $x++ ?>
<?php } //End of While ?>
```

Hey everyone,

I currently have a set of images listed as SDG1, SDG2... SDG17 and each image will have text that you hover. I am replicating [sustainable development in the UN website.](https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/sdgs)

Instead of copying the div over and over, I thought it would be easier to put it in a while loop and within that while loop, have a switch loop that will echo back the text based on the case. Right now, it will only echo the default.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: manual php -> switch case. You forgot about `break` in case block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add  a proper break after each case

```
switch($x) {
case 1: 
   $sdg_text = "End poverty in all its forms everywhere";
   break;
case 2:
   $sdg_text = 'End hunger, achieve food security and improved nutrition and promote sustainable agriculture';
   break;
case 3: 
  $sdg_text = "Ensure healthy lives and promote well-being for all at all ages";
  break;
default: echo '';
 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually its just one simple error. The problem is that you dont use `break;`. At the end of every case(default case too) you have to add `break;`.

> If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement
>   list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.

Comment: Wow.. how did I miss that! Thank you